# How do people edit a Dropbox text file in emacs? (specifically, todo.txt)

Tags: emacs, dropbox

I'd like to try out todo.txt, using the android app in combination with emacs on a mac.  I have not yet figured out a way to simply open the todo.txt file in emacs.  If I create a Finder alias to the todo.txt file in the Dropbox folder and open that in emacs, the contents are binary garbage.

How do people do this?

Comment: The writeup of Todo.txt suggests that it is a flat text file that can be viewed with any text editor.  There is likely a problem if your Todo.txt is gibberish.  See:  http://todotxt.com/  The problem is not likely Emacs-related.  To rule out Emacs as a potential problem, try opening the file in another text editor.  In addition, try using things like Finder open-with and select your application or simply open the application first and then open the file from within your text editor.  I'm not sure why you are creating an alias.

Comment: Thanks.  You're correct - I'm able to right-click and open with Emacs in a new window.  I created the alias because I'd like to do C-x C-f like I would  with any other file, and I don't know where dropbox hides itself on the real filesystem, or if it's kosher to open it there or only through the finder.  Unclear to me why the alias and Ctrl-x Ctrl-f didn't work.

Comment: Aha!  Dragging from the finder into an existing emacs window works.